# How can I efficiently move from a Pandas dataframe to JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, pandas

I've started using `pandas` to do some aggregation by date. My goal is to count all of the instances of a measurement that occur on a particular day, and to then represent this in `D3`. To illustrate my workflow, I have a queryset (from `Django`) that looks like this:

```
queryset = [{'created':"05-16-13", 'counter':1, 'id':13}, {'created':"05-16-13", 'counter':1, 'id':34}, {'created':"05-17-13", 'counter':1, 'id':12}, {'created':"05-16-13", 'counter':1, 'id':7}, {'created':"05-18-13", 'counter':1, 'id':6}]
```

I make a dataframe in `pandas` and aggregate the measure 'counter' by the day created:

```
import pandas as pd
queryset_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryset).set_index('id')
aggregated_df = queryset_df.groupby('created').sum()
```

This gives me a dataframe like this:

```
          counter
created          
05-16-13        3
05-17-13        1
05-18-13        1
```

As I'm using `D3` I thought that a `JSON` object would be the most useful. Using the `Pandas` `to_json()` function I convert my dataframe like this:

```
aggregated_df.to_json()
```

giving me the following `JSON` object

```
{"counter":{"05-16-13":3,"05-17-13":1,"05-18-13":1}}
```

This is not exactly what I want, as I would like to be able to access both the date, and the measurement. Is there a way that I can export the data such that I end up with something like this?

```
data = {"c1":{"date":"05-16-13", "counter":3},"c2":{"date":"05-17-13", "counter":1}, "c3":{"date":"05-18-13", "counter":1}}
```

I thought that if I could structure this differently on the `Python` side, it would reduce the amount of data formatting I would need to do on the `JS` side as I planned to load the data doing something like this:

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.counter; }));
```

I'm very open to suggestions of better workflows overall as this is something I will need to do frequently but am unsure of the best way of handling the connection between `D3` and `pandas`. (I have looked at several packages that combine both `python` and `D3` directly, but that is not something that I am looking for as they seem to focus on static chart generation and not making an svg)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Transform your date index back into a simple data column with `reset_index`, and then generate your json object by using the `orient='index'` property:

```
In [11]: aggregated_df.reset_index().to_json(orient='index')
Out[11]: '{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3},"1":{"created":"05-17-13","counter":1},"2":{"created":"05-18-13","counter":1}}'
```